# Wrong timezone nodejs mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, datetime, mongoose

I have a timezone problem when I try to store something in mongodb using mongoose.

I created a schema like this:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    created_at: {
        type: Date
    }
});
```

It is important in my code to find users in a date range ($gte and $lte).

The problem occurs when create users:

```
user.created_at = new Date();
```

In my database this user is created with a wrong timezone.

I had tried to use "[moment-timezone.js](http://momentjs.com/)" like:

```
user.created_at = moment().tz("America/Belem").format();
```

The problem with timezone still the same in mongodb, but when I console log "moment().tz("America/Belem").format()" I got the right timezone just in database it goes wrong, so I think the problem is with type Date in mongoose, **because it saving in UTC time, but I want in local time**.

I have tried to use type String instead of type Date in my schema and I got the right timezone with "moment-timezone.js", but my query for $gte and $lte to find the users didn't work anymore.

In this discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26150495/node-js-and-mongodb-time-zone-issue-utc-not-being-converted-correctly-by-driver) the problem is the same, but they say about change the server timezone to UTC, but they don't show how to do it. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083410/how-can-i-set-the-default-timezone-in-node-js) to change the server timezone but it doesn't work for me (I'm using windows 10) and I think it is not the right path.

Please help me with this issue. Show me the best way to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Please take a look at this. You should always try to store the time in UTC. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40425115/2683814

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply. I tried your solution but didn't work. :'(

Comment: what do you see in the db? how are the dates stored now ?

Comment: I got the same timezone problem as before. Nothing changed.

Comment: `Date` is always in UTC with MongoDB, which is honestly what you likely should be using regardless of what you're currently thinking. :)

Comment: Yeah. I got your point. I think you're right. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0); // hour,minute,seconds,milliseconds
user.created_at=d;
```

By this way you can set UTChours for "America/Belem".

For example America/Belem has UTC hours +5 then u can do

```
d.setUTCHours(5, 0, 0, 0);
```